# Is it possible to access parent object from within its lambda property?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, this

I need to access the instance of a class from inside the function stored in its constructor property, like this

```
data class Parent(
    val lambda: () -> Unit = {
        // I need the instance of the enclosing Parent here
        // this@Parent doesn't work
    }
)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you explain your use case here? There might be a better way to achieve that.

Comment: I deliberately kept the question simple because my use case is not. I mainly wanted to know whether such a thing is possible since it would make things easier for me. I got the answer so I'll have to go a different route. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible because the `Parent` object doesn't exist at the point when the lambda is created. The lambda is being passed as an argument to the constructor that will create the object, so the lambda has to be created first.

If the lambda was created inside the class instead of being passed to the constructor, you would be able to use `this` to access the containing object.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you want to do with the lambda. If you do not need to access `this` in order to access any private members of the class, you could define the lambda as a receiver function which is then called with the newly created object in the constructor or `init` block like this:

```kotlin
data class Parent(
    val lambda: Parent.() -> Unit
) {
    init {
        this.lambda()
    }
}
```

Then you can use `this` in the lambda that is a parameter of the constructor like this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val list = mutableListOf<Parent>()
    val parent = Parent { list.add(this) } // parent has been added to list on creation
}
```

However, as mentioned above, you cannot use this to break up the encapsulation of the class, e.g. if there is a private member `x` defined inside `Parent`, you cannot call `this.x`, but only publicly accessible members.

Comment: I was just about to post the exact same idea! (Though you go into more detail.)

Comment: This changes the function signature and it can be called with any instance of `Parent` which is not always desirable. But in cases where that is not important, this is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

make the constructor method private and create a static factory method then you can create the parent and the chield objects and then inject the reference. After that, you can access them as you wish.